# JSON stringify ignore some values in array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, object

The Array Look Like This:

```
["1", "2", R: "aviv", remove: function]
0: "1"
1: "2"
R: "Test"
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

When I Use JSON.stringify() for this array i get:

```
["1","2"]
```

This Because The array length is 2, How Can I Resolve It Please?
I need to make ajax post into php script with this array, and i lose some of nesesarry data.

Thank You,
Aviv

Comment: That is not an array...

Comment: Whatever is generating that is not generating valid JSON.  Perhaps replace the square brackets with curly ones and treat it as an object instead of an array?

Comment: Are you trying to use an array as an object? Try changing the brackets to `{` and `}`.

Comment: That is a valid associative array in PHP (the analog in JSON is an object) - but the transformation of one to the other is nontrivial.  What is your goal?  What should the final JSON look like?

Comment: the final target is to transfer array in ajax post into php script.

Comment: Something Like This: $.ajax({        
       type: "POST",
       url: "Cart/TTYY.php",
       data: { activitiesArray : JSON.stringify(Cart_Data), Method:"Rest", Id:Active_Table_Id },
       success: function(data) {
    //alert(data);      
       }
    });

Comment: and in php i get the array but with missing data, in this case R: "Test" is missing

Answer (score 2):

`["1", "2", R: "aviv", remove: function]` does not represent an array - it's invalid syntax.

Anyway, assuming the code was meant to portray an Array created as:

```
arr = ["1", "2"]
arr.R = "aviv"
arr.remove = function () {}
```

Then *neither* the `R` or `remove` properties will be serialized with JSON.stringify because it maps an Array to a JSON-Array.

While [JavaScript] Arrays are a specialization of Objects - in particular, they support "expando properties", JSON-Arrays and JSON-Objects are *distinct* data-types.

As such JSON-Arrays have *no way* to map keys and will *not map* additional properties: the actual implementation will iterate over the array indices `[0,arr.length)` as it maps the Array to a JSON-Array.

To map the extra keys as a JSON-Object, *start* with a [JavaScript] Object (not an Array) which will be mapped to a JSON-Object:

```
notArray = { 0: "1", 1: "2", R: "aviv", remove: function () {} }
```

Of course, perhaps the JSON should have a deeper structure: keep the mapping rules above in mind.

---

Here is sample output for both cases (note that the `function` was not mapped):

```
JSON.stringify(arr)       // -> ["1","2"]
JSON.stringify(notArray)  // -> {"0":"1","1":"2","R":"aviv"}
```